# Jenkins X error: secrets "jenkins" not found

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, minikube, jenkins-x

I am following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIdMveCe75c) tutorial. I'm trying to create a Jenkins X app locally in `minikube` and setting it up with Github.

But when I do `jx create quickstart` and follow the steps I get **`error: secrets "jenkins" not found`** as error.

Also, I found out that there is no secret named `jenkins`

```
root@Unix:/home/dadart/Downloads# kubectl get secret -n jx jenkins
Error from server (NotFound): secrets "jenkins" not found
```

Someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this post on Github with set-up "env settings" [before installation](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/1554).

You can find also in "Common problems" section ["How do I get the Password and Username for Jenkins?"](https://jenkins-x.io/faq/issues/#how-do-i-get-the-password-and-username-for-jenkins)

As per documentation - it seems you missed some part during installation:

> **What happens during installation**
>
> Jenkins X generates an administration password for Monocular/Nexus/Jenkins and save it in secrets. It then retrieves git secrets for the helm install (so they can be used in the pipelines).

this can be helpful "jenkins image" [issue](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx/issues/3047).

In case you still notice more problems with jenkis installation please open an issue [here](https://github.com/jenkins-x/jx)

Please share with your findings

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to create a Jenkins X Kubernetes cluster with Google Kubernetes Engine.

In my case, the issue has been solved by using --tekton flag:

```
jx create cluster gke --skip-login --tekton
```

[Creating a Jenkins X Kubernetes cluster with GKE throws exception: secrets "jenkins" not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66466525/creating-a-jenkins-x-kubernetes-cluster-with-gke-throws-exception-secrets-jenk/66466526#66466526)