# Creating a Jenkins X Kubernetes cluster with GKE throws exception: secrets "jenkins" not found

Tags: github, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, jenkins-x, gitops

When I try to create a Jenkins X Kubernetes cluster with GKE using this command:

```
jx create cluster gke --skip-login
```

The following exeption is thrown at the end of installation:

```
error creating cluster configuring Jenkins: creating Jenkins API token: after 3 attempts, last error: creating Jenkins Auth configuration: secrets "jenkins" not found
```

During installation I select the default settings and provide my own github settings, including generated personal access token, but I don't think that the github token is the issue in this case (I'm pretty sure all my github settings are correct)

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been solved by using --tekton flag:

```
jx create cluster gke --skip-login --tekton
```